# Proof of the Fourier Transform of 1 (in the distribution sense)

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am aware of the standard way to prove this but was wondering if this would work as well:

$\rm TF[1]\,=\,TF[1]\ast \delta\,=\,2\pi TF \left[1\times TF^{-1}[\delta]\right]\,=\,2\pi\delta$

Comment: Yes, why the question ? It is just a longer way to write it ...

Comment: I got 0point for that on a assignement and I can't figure out why...

Comment: The question was just to prove that this was indeed the Fourier Transform of 1.